# Why float: right/ pull-right dont work in the below code?

Tags: css, angular-ui, styling

```html
<div class="col-xs-12" style="padding:0px">
  <div class="col-xs-6 pull-left">
    <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Cooking Details</strong></div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <span class="col-xs-6 pull-left">Ingredient</span>
      <span class="pull-right col-xs-6 " style="padding-right:0px">Quantity</span>
    </div>
  <div>
<div>
```

Pull-right works fine for cooking details line, but for ingredient and quantity I am unable to format it with pull-right/float: right.

I am expecting quantity to be at the end of the div it is in. It is getting the 50% width but float:right is not working

Comment: You've tagged your question as Bootstrap 4, but pull-left and pull-right are not part of Bootstrap 4.

Comment: You need to explain more what is happening and what you want.  I think your last 2 `<div>` tags are meant to be closing tags `</div>`.  Please make a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  For bootsrap, codeply works great.  Here is your code [in codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/BrGeGl9mZi)

Comment: so now you have gotten rid of your bootstrap tag completely but you are using bootstrap.  Do you want bootstrap 3?  [Is this what you want](https://www.codeply.com/p/BrGeGl9mZi#) in bootstrap 4?

Comment: I did remove the tag because i am not sure in which boot strap pull-left/right comes, the problem is simple i want my float:right css property working and for that i can use pull-right/float-right depending on the model i am using. My issue is float:right also doesn't work and not the model/version of boot strap. I have checked pull-right is working on other divs

Comment: Did you see my link? [https://www.codeply.com/p/BrGeGl9mZi#](https://www.codeply.com/p/BrGeGl9mZi#).  That what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 3:  https://www.codeply.com/p/OSJMu17P9a

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="padding:0px">
    <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Cooking Details</strong></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <span class="pull-left">Ingredient</span>
        <span class="pull-right" style="padding-right:0px">Quantity</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap 4:  https://www.codeply.com/p/BrGeGl9mZi#

```
<div class="col-12" style="padding:0px">
    <div class="col-12"><strong>Cooking Details</strong></div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <span class="float-left">Ingredient</span>
        <span class="float-right" style="padding-right:0px">Quantity</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx removing col-xs from the span did help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you wanted something like this. When you add the col you have to use a div with row class a wrapper

#EDITED: WAY BETTER SOLUTION

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div style="padding: 0px;">
  <h4>
    <strong>Cooking Details</strong>
  </h4>

  <div>
    <span class="pull-left">Ingredient</span>
    <span class="pull-right">Quantity</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or Bootstrap 4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    
    <div>
      <h4>
        <strong>Cooking Details</strong>
      </h4>

      <div>
        <span class="float-left">Ingredient</span>
        <span class="float-right">Quantity</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: that works for bootstrap 3 but his post is tagged bootstrap 4 which replaced `pull-left` and `pull-right` with `float-left` and `float-right`

Comment: Yes, i was also guessing that but as i have seen pull-left i thought that he might be mistaken putting the tag but we can just change the tag to pull with float and done

Comment: Have you tried run my snippet?  Do you want something like this? You have also mistaken putting the col classes. Try to go through my snippet if you want something like that and also which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: If you are starting your answer with "I'm not sure if you wanted..." then you shouldn't be posting an answer.  You should be getting clarification from the OP in comments first.  Also, simply changing `pull` to `float` for bootstrap 4 will not work here.  Test it and see.  bootstrap 4 doesn't use `xs`.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisL , i will remember that from next time. :)

Comment: According to your code cooking detail and ingredient div will come in same line but what i want is cooking detail in first line, ingredient and quantity in other floating left and right respectively. And all these(cookingdtl/ingredient/quantity) to the left half of my page.

Comment: You can check updated answer, more simple solution,

Comment: @Niloy  That is still not what he wants.  Did you read his last comment?